# Using powershell to wait for a particular line to appear before continuing

Tags: powershell

I am wondering how I can tell powershell to wait for a certain log line before continuing with the script. I managed to use the following tell powershell what to look for,

```
Get-Content log.txt -Wait | select-string "keyword"
```

But powershell will never continue due the use of `-Wait`. Is there another way I can tell powershell to only wait for the line to appear once before proceeding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way to get this to work:

```
while($true){
    Get-Content .\test.log -Wait | Select-String "keyword" | %{ write-host Found $_; break}
}

write-host "start script"
```

<strike>Might not be efficient, but you can try it this way:</strike>

```
while(-not (gc .\test.log | select-string "keyword" )){ sleep 1}
write-host "start script"
```

Comment: is it possible this will miss an entry if 2 rows get inserted at the same time?

Comment: @JNK - Yeah I was looking at that. It is possible it can happen. So basically comes down to your answer.

Comment: Yeah I had invalid syntax and liked yours better.

Answer (score 2):

After some experimentation, it seems the following would do the job:

```
Get-Content log.txt -Wait | Select-String "keyword" | %{ write-host $_; break}
```

Comment: Ah, I added almost the same. But you want the script to start afterwards, but just a break will not go to next line in the script. See my answer if that helps